NSIS installer says environment variables are empty at runtime
Create basic.nsi to read an environment variable at runtime using ReadEnvStr:
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
Outfile "TestInstaller.exe"
Name "Test Installer"
InstallDir $DESKTOP\MyApp

Section "Install"
    ReadEnvStr $R0 "MY_VAR"
    ${If} $R0 == ""
        MessageBox MB_OK "MY_VAR is not set or is empty"
    ${Else}
        MessageBox MB_OK "MY_VAR value: $R0"
    ${EndIf}
SectionEnd

Then in powershell
> makensis basic.nsi
> set MY_VAR=1
> ./TestInstaller.exe

Gives "MY_VAR is not set or is empty". Similarly if I try using system calls:
Outfile "TestInstaller.exe"
Name "Test Installer"
InstallDir $DESKTOP\MyApp

Section "Install"
    System::Call 'kernel32::GetEnvironmentVariableA(t "MY_VAR", t .R0, i ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}) i .r1'

    IntCmp $R1 0 env_not_found env_found

    env_not_found:
        MessageBox MB_OK "MK_UPDATE_INSTALLER is not set or is empty"
        Goto end

    env_found:
        MessageBox MB_OK "MK_UPDATE_INSTALLER value: $R0"

    end:
SectionEnd

If I try to loop over every environment variable, it says there aren't any:
Outfile "PrintEnvVarsInstaller.exe"
Name "Print Env Vars Installer"
InstallDir $DESKTOP\MyApp

Section "Install"
    ; Get a pointer to the environment block
    System::Call 'kernel32::GetEnvironmentStringsA() p .r0'

    ; Initialize a pointer variable to iterate over the environment block
    StrCpy $R1 $R0

    loop:
    ; Get the current string pointed to by $R1
    System::Call '*$R1(&t0 .R2)'

    ; Check if we reached the end of the environment block (null string)
    StrCmp $R2 "" done

    ; Display the current environment variable
    MessageBox MB_OK "$R2"

    ; Move the pointer to the next string (environment variable)
    System::Call 'kernel32::lstrlenA(t $R2) i .r3'
    IntOp $R1 $R1 + $R3
    IntOp $R1 $R1 + 1

    ; Repeat the loop
    Goto loop

    done:
    ; Free the environment strings block
    System::Call 'kernel32::FreeEnvironmentStringsA(p $R0) i .r1'

    MessageBox MB_OK "done"

SectionEnd

Gives "done" immediately. Python os.getenv and Write-Host "MY_VAR is set to: $env:MY_VAR" detect the environment variable just fine.

That's weird that there's no error. $env:MY_VAR=1 is the way. Otherwise with set-variable you're making a variable called MY_VAR=1 with no value. Adding -verbose helps, and dir variable:.  Set-strictmode or powershell 7 doesn't catch it.
set my_var=1 -verbose

VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Set variable" on target 
  "Name: my_var=1 Value: "


dir variable:my_*

Name                           Value
----                           -----
my_var=1


${my_var=1}

<# no output #>


gcm set

CommandType     Name                                          Version    Source
-----------     ----                                          -------    ------
Alias           set -> Set-Variable


Yeah I did $env:MY_VAR=1; ./TestInstaller.exe too, doesn't work either. Also python and Write-Host can pick it up with "MY_VAR" so I must've set it for the shell correctly too. Don't have access to the machine right now but I can double check later.

yeah this isn't the problem, the variable names are fine. The problem seems to be the installer just doesn't inherit environment variables for some reason. If I update PATH in powershell and compile the nsi script to print PATH in the message box instead, it doesn't print the new PATH

Seems to be because I'm running the installer with admin privileges
